# Any way to remap "Frame Selected" for edit mode in 2.8?

Tags: mesh

It seem that in 2.8 I can't remap "Frame Selected" for edit mode. I have to use the <kbd>Num .</kbd> all the time which is tedious of course. In previous version I could remap it to "F" which is an industry standard and I think blender should have it as well.